# How to read data from txt between 2 lines with the same symbol?

Tags: matlab

I have a lot of .txt files (<1000 lines each). The data format is the following (the picture): there are some lines in the beginning that I don't need, then the line with '*', then the lines with data that I need to extract from the file, then again a line with '*' and some comments that I don't need.

Is there any way to do that? I have a lot of such files. The matter is that in every file the number of lines before the first '*' is different. So, is there any way to read the data in between of two '*'? I tried all the functions but I am a beginner and just cannot come up with the right idea...

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is quite simple with regular expressions:

```
usefulData = regexp(fileread('abg06.txt'), '(?<=\*).*?(?=\*)', 'match','once');
```